# Atmel Studio facing some problems due to code optimization

Tags: atmelstudio, atmega16

I am using atmel studio 7. I have a key detection logic that works when optimization is turned off(-O0) but does not work when its turned on. I am detecting the key using an ISR there are four keys connected to PORTB 0..3 in a matrix fashion like [this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P39Lv.png)

PB2 and PB3 is always set as input-pullup. I am switching PB0 and PB1 between Input-Tristate and Output-Low(Playing with the DDRB0 and DDRB1 bits only). Following is the key detection logic(Inside an ISR):

```
uint8_t tmp=0,v=0;
for(uint8_t i=0;i<2;i++){
    DDRB=(DDRB&0xFC)|(0x01<<i);
    tmp=(~PINB)&0x0C;if(tmp!=0x00) v=v|tmp|(0x01<<i);
    DDRB=DDRB&0xFC;while((PINB&0x0C)!=0x0C);  //This line
}
```

'Optimize for size(-Os)' is selected. When i remove 5th line value of 'tmp' changes when I press any key. Otherwise tmp is always read as zero. I need 5th line for the debounce logic.

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Oops..!! I figured It out...my bad...I havent taken into account, the charging and discharging due to input capacitances at the pins...

Comment: It seems I have to add a hardcoded delay after all...there's no escaping that...